# flex set border on dynamic added object?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, layout, actionscript, adobe

Im adding video windows to a video object inside mxml file

```
videoMovie = new Video(120,80);
```

Now would it be possible to apply a rounded border of 2px on this somehow?

I know you can use

```
    <s:controlBarContent>
    <s:Label text="cornerRadius:" />
    <s:HSlider id="slider"
            minimum="0"
            maximum="100"
            value="2"
            change="slider_change(event);"/>
</s:controlBarContent>
```

On regular objects but cannot find out how to do this with dynamically added ones :(

Answer (score 0):

The Video object is a native Flash player class -- not a Flex class. So it doesn't do all the fancy things a Flex component can do, like having a border, or a cornerRadius style.

The easiest solution is to wrap your Video object in a Flex component that has the functionality you need. But you cannot just simply do: flexComponent.addChild(videoObject);

You'll need to do something like this:

```
var video:Video = new Video();
var uiComponent:UIComponent = new UIComponent();
// UIComponent allows you to add non Flex children to it w/addChild()
// but you can't do this w/the Flex container classes (like Group, etc.)
uiComponent.addChild(video);
```

Now that your Video object is wrapped in a UIComponent, you can add that UIComponent to any Flex container ...

```
var container:BorderContainer = new BorderContainer();
container.addElement(uiComponent);
// now set your border/corner radius styles...
container.setStyle("cornerRadius", 2);
container.setStyle("borderColor", #FF0000);
```

This is a common approach for using non-Flex components (like Video or Sprite) as children of Flex components. I'm sure you can find a lot more about this by searching on phrases like "adding a Sprite to a Flex component"

Cheers!